# truncated model estimation, on an interval of unobserved variable Y*

Tags: econometrics, model, probit, truncated-normal-distribution

$Pr[L<Y^*<U]=Pr[Y^*<U]-Pr[Y^*<L]$
           $=F^*(U)-F^*(L)$

$lnL_n(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^nd_iln[F^*(U|x_i,\theta)-F^*(L|x_i,\theta)]$

^is the above likelihood function appropriate for this truncated model (Where Y* is the unobserved variable with observable bounds)? how would I go about estimating beta and sigma^2?[image: question link]

Comment: According to this model, $\Pr(L\le Y^{*}\le U) = 1$ because $Y^{*}$ *must* lie between $L$ and $U$ when it is observed.  Notice that the expression for $L_n$ you wrote down doesn't even depend on the observations $y_i$! Presumably ("we discussed data truncation from below") your class notes give you a template from which you can generalize: have you tried that?  Where did it take you?

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. so the lecture notes are somewhat confusing to me which is why I'm on here. following your advice, I found something in the textbook which follows a truncated MLE approach for using truncation from below at L, but I'm not sure what the log likelihood function would look like for a lower and upper bound interval like the one given above

Comment: Note that the MLE for truncated distributions may be very unstable.  https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/14697688.2012.752103

Comment: I think the professor more importantly wants to see that we can identify a likelihood function that needs to be maximized, and I'm not sure how it should be set up

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're asking for a reasonable hint, so let's deal with the truncation, which is the heart of the problem.

**First it's desirable to modify the question:** if $L$ and $U$ are "observed" bounds as stated, then the *true* bounds must be introduced as additional parameters in the model. I don't believe that's what the person who set this question intended you to do (but let us know if that's incorrect). Let's assume these bounds are *stipulated independently of any of the observations,* so that we may treat them as constants.

Let $\Phi$ be the standard Normal cumulative distribution function and let $\phi$ be its density, $\phi(x) = \exp(-x^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}.$ Conditional on the regressor $x,$ the model states that the chance $Y^{*}$ lies between $L$ and $U$ is

$$\Pr(L \le Y^{*} \le U\mid x) = \Phi\left(\frac{U - x^\prime \beta}{\sigma}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{L - x^\prime \beta}{\sigma}\right).$$

**Thus, to obtain a proper probability distribution you have to divide the density of $Y$ by this quantity** (this is a direct consequence of the formula for conditional probabilities, where we are conditioning $Y$ on the event $L \le Y^{*}\le U$), giving

$$f(y;\beta,\sigma\mid x) = \frac{1}{\sigma}\frac{\phi\left(\frac{y - x^\prime \beta}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi\left(\frac{U - x^\prime \beta}{\sigma}\right) - \Phi\left(\frac{L - x^\prime \beta}{\sigma}\right)}.$$

These are the terms out of which you need to construct the likelihood.  You cannot ignore the denominators because they depend on the parameters $(\beta,\sigma).$

Comment: wouldn't my likelihood function just be an argmax of the density function for Y (the second equation that you have written down I believe?)..or am I totally lost?

Comment: also, would this by chance be considered a latent index model? thanks very much for your help on this.